# I can't find python module on monjaro linux

Tags: python, module, directory

I using arch linux - monjaro

Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.84.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.49-1-MANJARO (64-bit)

and I can't find "Pyside2" module, I searched in user dir, in root, I find just python2.7 with one dir "site-packages" and python3.9 without lib dir, then when I opened site-packages I found others modules but not my, and yes I installed it from pip

```
pip install PySide2
```

Comment: My pip dir : pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
But there is not PySide2 folder

Comment: What actually happened when you ran `pip install pyside2`?  Are you trying to install it for Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: ```
[catalin@catalin ~]$ pip install pyside2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyside2 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken2==5.15.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyside2) (5.15.2)
[catalin@catalin ~]$
```
And i installing for python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install build dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake libqt4-dev libphonon-dev python2.7-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev qtmobility-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```

Install latest pip distribution into the Python you installed in the first step:
download `get-pip.py` and run it using the python interpreter of your Python 2.7 installation using a command prompt:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python2.7 get-pip.py
```

Install latest wheel distribution:

```
$ sudo pip2.7 install wheel
```

Building PySide distribution
Download PySide source distribution:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PySide/PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
```

Extract the source distribution:

```
$ tar -xvzf PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
```

Switch to the distribution directory:

```
$ cd PySide-1.2.4
```

Build the wheel binary distribution:

```
$ python2.7 setup.py bdist_wheel --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

Optionally you can build standalone version of distribution with embedded Qt libs:

```
$ python2.7 setup.py bdist_wheel --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 --standalone
```

https://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building/linux.html

Ok, if that doesn't work, try the snap store.

https://snapcraft.io/pyside2

Comment: I using arch linux, not debian based, I mentioned that I using manjaro, if u can translate code for arch pls?

Comment: @Cătălin Can you please check the question as answered and vote up.